# Find value in a vba dynamic table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dynamic table of strings that I defined in vba (I precise that it is not an XL table) and I want to check if a specific value is present in this table. Here is a portion of my function:

```
Dim tableOfSizes() As String
sizeTable(0)=size1
sizeTable(1)=size2
sizeTable(2)=size3
'size2 and size3 are optional parameters of the function

If instr(tableOfSizes, "Medium") <> 0 Then
' Action if "Medium" is found in the table
End If
```

but it seems that instr do not work for tables, or at least, for dynamic tables. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *1D-array* you can use following approaches.

**Way №1** [`Filter function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fat7fw0s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
If UBound(Filter(tableOfSizes, "Medium")) <> -1 Then
    ' Action if "Medium" is found in the table
End If
```

**Way №2 (*`for Excel-VBA`*)** [`Application.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("Medium", tableOfSizes, 0)) Then
    ' Action if "Medium" is found in the table
End If
```

---

For *multi-dimmension arrays* you can use following function:

```
Function contains(arr, elem) As Boolean
    Dim a
    contains = False
    For Each a In arr
        If a = elem Then
            contains = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

and then:

```
If contains(tableOfSizes, "Medium") Then
    ' Action if "Medium" is found in the table
End If
```