# Finding an Integer in Array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi' I'm using VBA for Excel.

I was wondering if there's an easy way finding out if I have a certain number in an array of integers - something like the `Filter` function for strings - only for integer.

Or should I do a for loop and go over all of the values in the array?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I  may be speaking too soon, but in my experience, I loop.

Comment: @Bramat, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224874/find-value-in-a-vba-dynamic-table/23224987#23224987

Comment: @simoco I wrote a function quite similar - but thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using excel, you can use the following function:

```
nindex = Application.Match(value, myArray, 0) + LBound(myArray) - 1
```